# Get entity by id jaydata

Tags: jaydata

I created Task table in WebSQL database with jaydata.

```
$data.Entity.extend("Task", {
        Id: {
            type: "int", 
            key: true, 
            computed: true
        },
        Task: {
            type: "text", 
            required: true
        },
        Last: {
            type: "date"
        },
        .....
$data.EntityContext.extend("TaskDatabase", {
    Tasks: {
        type: $data.EntitySet, 
        elementType: Task
    }
});

taskDB = new TaskDatabase("Work");
```

[image: Task table]

Why my table has two coloumns "Id"?

I want to get entity from table by Id. How I can do it? Thanks for answers.

I tried (companyId = 2):

```
    taskDB.Tasks.read(companyId).then(function (item) {
    console.log(item.Task);
});
```

and

```
    taskDB.Tasks.single(function (task) 
        { return task.Id == this.Id }, 
        { Id: companyId },
        renderCompany);
```

Comment: `var task = taskDB.Tasks.attachOrGet({ Id: companyId });` is work, but when I put this code to taskDB.onReady() id doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for the JayData project

The essense is this:

```
taskDB.onReady(function() {
      taskDB.Tasks.find(newTask.TaskId)
                  .then(function(item) {
                    document.write("Found:" + JSON.stringify(item) +"<br>");
...
```

Please, refer to this plunk I've created on how to create new items or query them back: http://plnkr.co/edit/OTsMEDUX6OwzT8jcom7q?p=preview

As for the duplicate id: it is just a display thing - the chrome resource viewer display the primar key column as a kind of row header.